# Shortcut to turn on/off firefox addons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to turn on and off a firefox addon using a keyboard shortcut. Is this even posible?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.06, so a terminal command to do so would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely possible:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm');
AddonManager.getAddonByID('Profilist@jetpack', function(addon) {
  if (addon.userDisabled) {
       //enable it
       addon.userDisabled = false;
  } else {
       //disable it
       addon.userDisabled = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, as I can't bind this code to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: So you knew how to do this? And your question is really asking how to add a keyboard shortcut? You asked `Is it even possible?`. I'm sure you know that keyboard shortcuts are possible everyone everywhere does it. If your question was about keyboard shortcuts and how to add please make new topic.